# Why is MSB3245 not failing the build?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, msbuild

I have a situation where I have a solution with a missing reference (showing the exclamation mark) however the build succeeds with message:

> C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\MSBuild\12.0\bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(1697,5):
>   warning MSB3245: Could not resolve this reference. Could not locate
>   the assembly "EntityFramework". Check to make sure the assembly exists
>   on disk. If this reference is required by your code, you may get
>   compilation errors.

This is quite worrying as I would've expected it to **fail the build**.

Is there a reason behind having MSB3245 just as a warning?

Comment: The compiler is the ultimate arbiter.  If it can't find the reference assembly then it will yell loudly enough.  Why it doesn't is unguessable from the question.  Arbitrarily: check the content of the .csproj file and verify that the reference has the HintPath element.

Comment: The reference is broken. However I'm trying to understand why that doesn't make the build break. Intuition tells me otherwise.

Comment: @m.edmondson, did you find any real explanation why build not fails when missing project references exist?

Answer (score 1):

The warning you see is from the ResolveAssemblyReferences target of MSBuild.  Its job to determine full paths to your reference assemblies based on the information given in the project XML.  For example, a reference like `<Reference Include="System.Xml" />` is found in the Global Assembly Cache (GAC) by ResolveAssemblyReferences and the full path of the DLL is passed to the compiler.

If a full path to a reference assembly cannot be determined, a reference is not passed to the compiler.  If none of your actual code depends on the reference, then compilation will succeed and the build will continue on.

You must not have any code that actually depends on `EntityFramework` that is being passed to the compiler.